# filtering using checkbox in android

Tags: android, checkbox, filtering

I am developing an android app where user perform check box selection and at that time total number of displaying item get changed like this [link](http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2011/09/28/filter-js-client-side-search-filtering-using-json-and-jquery/)

My data is also at client side. How can I perform same operation like above in android? I am using android api 16.

Comment: The concepts used above seem completely unrelated to android. Though the concept of filter.js will only work with Javascript not Java so you'll have to research and find an appropriate alternative. As it stands this question is rather minimal as you are pretty much asking us to give you entire code

Comment: Both `ListView` and `GridView` are easily filterable by manipulating the `ListAdapter` from which they draw data. But this would require custom data objects and overriding filtering methods of Adapter.

Comment: @Carl , I am not asking entire code.I just want suitable direction so that I can start my work.

Comment: still I am waiting for some valuable help.